# Is that possible to save a string variable and cookiecontainer in the same local file?

Tags: c#, serialization, binaryformatter

I need to use a string variable(a guid parameter) and a cookie container in other project and i need to keep theese locally. I am already keep cookie container and use that code below for it:

```
public static void WriteCookiesToDisk(string file, CookieContainer cookieJar)
        {
            using (Stream stream = File.Create(file))
            {
                try
                {
                    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                    formatter.Serialize(stream, cookieJar);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.Out.WriteLine("Cookie yazdırılıken hata oluştu: " + e.GetType());
                }
            }
        }
```

I need to know is there a way to keep guid parameter(string var.) and cookie container in the same file and reach these in the other project as if they are variables.

Comment: If only you could somehow wrap the cookie container and the string in some kind of parent object that holds both of them, and then serialize that....

Comment: @john hm... its makes sense but i am jr developer and i dont know how can i create a parent object that holds two differend kind of variables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class to store both:

```
[Serializable]
public class Container
{
    public string MyStringValue { get; set; }
    public CookieContainer Cookies { get; set; }
}
```

Create an instance with both objects in it:

```
var objectToSerialize = new Container() { MyStringValue = "hello", Cookies = cookieJar };
```

And then serialize it:

```
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
formatter.Serialize(stream, objectToSerialize);
```